# Double underscore method for ordering the list returned by the view based on a field in another model not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to order the list the view returns based on a field in another model. I read the [documentation over here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) and it says I could do that by using the model's name, if the ordering is specified in the model's meta.

**View**

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    ordering = ['choice']
```

**Model**

```
  class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.choice_text

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['-votes']
```

**template(polls/results.html)**

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

I did that, it works but I have different views which require the same model to be ordered in different ways, say one by it's name and another by votes. How can I achieve something like that?

For example I am looking for something like

**View 1**

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    ordering = ['-choice__votes']
```

**View 2**

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    ordering = ['-choice__choice_text']
```

Comment: There can be multiple `Choice`s for a given `Question`. According to which choice should the ORM sort Questions?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes but even in the first case Question has lot of choices and each choice has specific no of votes, yet it retrieves in the correct order. Like that I want to retrieve by choice_name in one and votes in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `queryset` attribute on the view class instead of a model, and add the ordering to that.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all().order_by('-choice__choice_text')
```

**Edit**

You need to specifically order the choices, rather than the questions. Normally you would do this by adding the `order_by` call when you look up the choices, but since you're doing that in the template you can't pass the ordering value there. Instead, you could define two methods on the Question class itself which return choices in the relevant order:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    def choices_by_votes(self):
        return self.choice_set.order_by('-votes')

    def choices_by_text(self):
        return self.choice_set.order_by('choice_text')
```

and use them in the template:

```
{% for choice in question.choices_by_votes %}
```

Comment: Well this is an answer to your general question of how to specify ordering per view. On the specifics of your ordering, trying to order the queryset here doesn't really make sense because you're only accessing a single Question. It seems like it's actually the *choices* you want to order, is that right?

Comment: In which case you need to show how and where you're iterating over the choices.

Comment: Yea I got to order the choices, right sorry, I added the template.

Comment: Great thanks, but just a question as a noob, is this some kind of workaround i.e are there better ways that I should have actually implemented this logic that it is flexible to change?